# how to draw curve with four points

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, bezier

I can draw a curve using bezier path, but instead of specifying two control points, I want to specify two points that the path go through it, shown as following

[image]

the startPoint is (10,90), end point is (70,70), and the curve pass (20, 50), which is the peak point. and (60,100). Please let me know how to draw it.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6054002/drawing-a-moving-sine-wave-anti-aliased?lq=1. Hope this will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

From "Bézier curve" article in Wikipedia:

> Any series of any 4 distinct points can be converted to a cubic Bézier curve that goes through all 4 points in order. Given the starting and ending point of some cubic Bézier curve, and any two other distinct points in sequence along that curve, the control points for the original Bézier curve can be recovered.[3]

and at the end follows link to http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/html/bezier_interpolation.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[UIBezierPath](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html)'s**  [addCurveToPoint:controlPoint1:controlPoint2:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBezierPath/addCurveToPoint%3acontrolPoint1%3acontrolPoint2%3a) method.

```
CGPoint startPt, endPt, cPt1, cPt2;
// init points here
UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
[path moveToPoint:startPt];
[path addCurveToPoint:endPt controlPoint1:cPt1 controlPoint2:cPt2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming we have four points `D0(x0,y0)`, `D1(x1,y1)`, `D2(x2,y2)`, `D2(x3,y3)`. We have to find Bezier cubic spline `P0-P1-P2-P3` passing through `D0`, `D1`, `D2` and `D3`.

Obviously,

```
P0 = D0
P3 = D2
```

Then there are infinite number of Bezier splines passing through point `D1` and point `D2` defined by equations

```
P2 = (D1 - (1-t1)^3 * P0 - t1^3 * P3) / (3*(1-t1)*t1^2) -
     (1-t1) * P1/t1;
P2 = (D2 - (1-t2)^3 * P0 - t2^3 * P3) / (3*(1-t2)*t2^2) -
     (1-t2) * P1/t2;
```

where `t1` is Bezier curve parameter corresponding to point `D1` and `t2` is corresponding parameter of `D2`.

Solving this system of equations will give us `P1`

```
P1 = t2*(D1 - (1-t1)^3 * P0 - t1^3 * P3) / (3*(1-t1)*t1*(t2-t1)) -
     t1*(D2 - (1-t2)^3 * P0 - t2^3 * P3) / (3*(1-t2)*t2*(t2-t1));
```

We still need to define `t1` and `t2`. Their values can be pretty much anything as long as they are not equal and not equal to `1`. One obvious choice is `0.25` and `0.75`.

Here is a resulting curve for a set of random input values

[image: example plot]

Then `P1` and `P2` can be used as controlPoint1 and controlPoint2 in 
UIBezierPath's [addCurveToPoint:controlPoint1:controlPoint2](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBezierPath/addCurveToPoint:controlPoint1:controlPoint2:) method.